# Calculation of the $3\times 3$ exponent matrix via Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential, cayley-hamilton

I have a random $3\times 3$ matrix $A$.

How can I calculate $e^A$ by $E$ (the identity matrix), $A$ and $A^2$, using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

I need a general expression that includes only the trace, determinant and signature (tensor invariants) of a given matrix $A$.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you want to use the Cayley Hamilton theorem, or are you merely trying to express that you want an expression of the form $e^A = c_1 E + c_2 A + c_3 A^2$?

Comment: Also, please explicitly state what you mean by $E$. I strongly suspect that you mean the identity matrix.

Comment: Finally, note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to tell us why you are asking this question (e.g. is this an approach to a research problem? A homework problem of some kind?), what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you have.

Comment: I really want an expression of the form $e^A = c_1 E + c_2 A + c_3 A^2$ . I know for sure that such a decomposition is possible precisely with the help of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.